# Do software for creating Live Medias work whatever the CPU architecture of the target is?

Tags: boot, liveusb, cpu-architecture, rufus

So say with a software, you're flashing an image of Linux distro in a certain CPU architecture (say x86-32) to a USB drive & it's been know to work quite well. Then with the image of the same distro, of the same version, but in a different CPU architecture (say powerpc), how do we know that the software will create a Live Media that will even boot?

See, as far as I know, storage partition become bootable, not just by having the right IDs in the right physical offsets, file structure or files that are purely text based, but also because of small binary programs (bootloaders) there. These binary programs, at this point no doubt, runs raw on the CPU. So it does matter that the software adds the right CPU version of the binaries.

So do we have to be watchful of the flasher we use, in this regard? I've been using Rufus to flash Live CDs for x86's. Yet people also seem to use it for flashing the their USB or SD with Raspbian for their Raspberry Pi, an ARM machine.

Comment: Yes,  it should work regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Rufus developer here. I think you are under the impression that utilities like Rufus add a lot of extra boot files, but that is not the case. Especially, Raspbian images will be written in DD mode, which means that the content is written bit for bit, without any alteration on the target media, and especially with nothing added or removed by the utility creating the drive. This means that, in that case, the whole boot process is directed by the image (and the people who created the image), and it doesn't matter whether the bootable drive was created on a CPU that uses a completely different architecture from the one that's going to boot the image.

Now, in some cases, Rufus may add extra bootloader components. For instance, if you are creating a Windows bootable drive for an ARM64 machine, and the ISO you are using contains an `install.wim` that is larger than 4 GB, then Rufus will add its [UEFI:NTFS](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/) bootloader to enable booting from NTFS (since FAT32 cannot be used to write files that are larger than 4 GB).

In that case, then yes the extra bootloader component needs to be in a binary executable format that the target CPU can understand. But that is still not an issue, as, in the case of UEFI:NTFS, we anticipated that so that Rufus can and does provide a bootloader for all of the CPU architectures that are currently compatible with UEFI (which means x86_32, x86_64, ARM and ARM64 -- and if UEFI ever adds MIPS or other architectures, we will of course also add bootloaders for these), therefore you can create a bootable drive for those archs without having to worry. And the same is true for the Syslinux or GRUB components we may add, as these only target x86_32 (yes, even as GRUB can be used on ARM, because the only situation where we need to add an extra GRUB component is for BIOS boot, which has **never** been implemented outside of x86).

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: I didn't fully understand what you were saying in the last two sentences. I'm only opposed to saying that GRUB is only targeted for system with BIOS & x86 architectures (though true, it seems only BIOS is only found in IBM PC -- x86 family). I do believe that there is a reason it's named GRand Unified Bootloader. I may have to look it up, but as far as I know Syslinux is the same. Don't condescend me.